# Proof using Identity theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove that no two distinct holomorphic functions agree on all of $\frac{1}{n}$ where $n$ is an integer.

So the identity theorem says that two functions $f,g$ are identical iff the set of all complex numbers in a domain having $f(z) = g(z)$ have a limit point in that domain.

So $\frac{1}{n}$ does have a limit point in the complex plane right? It may not belong to the set, but it does have a limit point $z=0$.

What is incorrect in this argument? What is the correct argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article [Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem):

> [G]iven functions f and g holomorphic on a connected open set D [...] Specifically, if two holomorphic functions f and g on a domain D agree on a set S which has an accumulation point c in D then f = g on all of D

So the accumulation point must be part of the domain. For example you cannot apply your argument for two functions $f,g : \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb C$ because the accumulation point $0$ does not belong to the domain $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: why does the domain have to be C∖{0} ?

Comment: It's an example for a domain where you cannot apply your argument "two functions are the same for all points "\frac 1n" -> they are the same". See the answer by @curiosity for an counterexample...

Answer (score 2):

Just look at $f(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$ and $g(x)=0$, they agree on all points $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ but are not the same...

Comment: wasn't the question statement to prove the opposite? **no** two

Comment: no two ... if the conditions are respected and one of those conditions is to have the limit point in the domain

Comment: I don't understand. You just gave me two distinct holomorphic functions which agree on all points 1/n. The question statement (first line in question) says the opposite. So you say the question statement is wrong?

Comment: look at @tampis ' answer. Without some conditions, the statement is wrong.